# Ruby/Rails terminal commands are missing first line of error output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu-20.04, oh-my-zsh

I've been suffering from this issue for a rather long time and have mostly put up with it but I can't anymore. I have tried to look for a solution to no avail.

Whenever I try to perform a ruby/rails call from my terminal, I am missing the first line of any error output.

As you can see in the example below, the first line, which includes the actual error message, is missing.

For more info:
I am running Ubuntu 20.04 with a zsh/oh-my-zsh shell, but this also happens in bash. This has been happening for several versions of ruby now.

Example:

```
➜  CODE_BASE git:(branch_name) ✗ rails routes
Traceback (most recent call last):
    42: from bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
    41: from bin/rails:9:in `require'
    40: from /home/penguin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.6/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    39: from /home/penguin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.6/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
    38: from /home/penguin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.6/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/command/base.rb:69:in `perform'
    37: from /home/penguin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.6/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
    36: from /home/penguin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.6/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
    35: from /home/penguin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.6/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    34: from /home/penguin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.6/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/commands/routes/routes_command.rb:13:in `perform'
    33: from /home/penguin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.6/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/command/actions.rb:15:in `require_application_and_environment!'
    32: from /home/penguin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.6/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/command/actions.rb:28:in `require_environment!'
    31: from /home/penguin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.6/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/application.rb:367:in `require_environment!'
    30: from /home/penguin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.6/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `require'
    29: from /home/penguin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.6/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
    28: from /home/penguin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.6/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `block in require'
    27: from /home/penguin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.6/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `require'
    26: from /home/penguin/Projects/CODE_BASE/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    25: from /home/penguin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.6/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/application.rb:391:in `initialize!'
    24: from /home/penguin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.6/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
    23: from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.6/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
    22: from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.6/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
    21: from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.6/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    20: from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.6/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
    19: from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.6/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
    18: from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.6/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    17: from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.6/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    16: from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.6/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    15: from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.6/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
    14: from /home/penguin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.6/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
    13: from /home/penguin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.6/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
    12: from /home/penguin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.6/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
    11: from /home/penguin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.6/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:195:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    10: from /home/penguin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.6/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:10:in `execute'
     9: from /home/penguin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.6/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:83:in `execute'
     8: from /home/penguin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.6/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:35:in `block in updater'
     7: from /home/penguin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.6/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:21:in `reload!'
     6: from /home/penguin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.6/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:47:in `load_paths'
     5: from /home/penguin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.6/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:47:in `each'
     4: from /home/penguin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.6/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:47:in `block in load_paths'
     3: from /home/penguin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.6/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:326:in `load'
     2: from /home/penguin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.6/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
     1: from /home/penguin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.6/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:326:in `block in load'
/home/penguin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.6/gems/activesupport-6.1.4.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:326:in `load':
```

Comment: Might be a long shot but try with the latest Ruby 3.1.

Comment: Possibly a terminal or prompt formatting issue. What happens if you redirect the error message to a file instead of the terminal, is the missing line present in the file or not?